# Registering input on the CLI to java program while executing *.jar with node.js child_process.spawn

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

I am ultimately trying to write a convenient wrapper for a java-program with the help of node so I was making some tests.

I have some executable jar which initializes some simple question and answer flow on the command line (just using a Scanner in java) and with the help of another post on SO 
I am at least able to initialize execution like that (using cmd as I am on Windows 10 with this PC):

```
'use strict';

const
    { spawn } = require('child_process'),
    dir = spawn('cmd', ['/c', 'java -jar myTestJar.jar']);

dir.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(`stdout: ${data}`));
dir.stderr.on('data', data => console.log(`stderr: ${data}`));
dir.on('close', code => console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`));
```

Fine so far; I get my nice prompt asking me my question where I would now
input something but I can't type anything to the CLI anymore. It seems node is still running (which would make sense for me having no experience with this at all but I would think it is still running as the spawned command hasn't finished, so no exit for node). Is it possible to register input for my java-Scanner in this situation; if yes: how?

If any more information is needed, please tell me and I will try to provide it.

Comment: Add this as the third argument to `spawn`: `{  stdio: 'inherit' }` and see if that works for you.

Comment: or try this: https://github.com/chjj/pty.js